# In Magento 1.9, why are order emails send through the queue, while Invoice emails are sent directly?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email, email-scheduler

In Magento 1.9, why are order emails send through the queue, while Invoice emails are sent directly? I checked the code for Order and Invoice, and the `order-sendNewOrderEmail` uses the queue, while `invoice->sendEmail()` skips it completely. It's making the order email be sent after the invoice email instead of before in case the order is approved automatically!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Orders email are sent using the queue for different reasons:

- Avoid frontend slowdown while sending out the email
- Resend on failure
- Avoid errors on checkout/post-checkout

**Solution 1 (send order's email immediately):**

If you like to send order email immediately you can consider overriding the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail()` method by chainging the following lines:

```
/** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
$emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
$emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
    ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
    ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
    ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);

$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

to:

```
    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
    $mailer->send();
```

**Solution 2 (send invoices using queue):**

The opposite solution is to let invoices use the queue:

You must override `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::sendEmail` changing:

```
// Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $order,
                'invoice'      => $this,
                'comment'      => $comment,
                'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
            )
        );
        $mailer->send();
```

To:

```
// Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $order,
                'invoice'      => $this,
                'comment'      => $comment,
                'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
            )
        );

        $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
        $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
          ->setEntityType('order_invoice')
          ->setEventType('new_invoice');

        $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the suggestion! I actually did the same, but the other way around. I added the invoice to the queue instead. It worked, but I wonder if it's also right to do?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll add to my post for other users.

Comment: Seems to good solution. Will give a try

Comment: I used solution 1 and it worked form me. Thanks